# How create new route with interface IEndpointRouteBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have upgraded project to asp.net core 3.0 and would like to use Endpoint routing.

I have following old method:

```cs
public static IRouteBuilder MapLocalizedRoute(this IRouteBuilder routeBuilder,
                string name, string template, object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens)
{
    if (routeBuilder.DefaultHandler == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(routeBuilder));
    }

    //get registered InlineConstraintResolver
    var inlineConstraintResolver = routeBuilder.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInlineConstraintResolver>();

    //create new generic route
    routeBuilder.Routes.Add(new LocalizedRoute(routeBuilder.DefaultHandler, name, template,
            new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new RouteValueDictionary(constraints), 
            new RouteValueDictionary(dataTokens), inlineConstraintResolver));

    return routeBuilder;
}
```

I need change to type **this IEndpointRouteBuilder routeBuilder**. 
But how me implement adding of new generic router? Interface IEndpointRouteBuilder dosent have property Routes and I can't use **routeBuilder.Routes.Add**...

Comment: What do you want to achieve?For the `LocalizedRoute` in your code , did you want a localizer url scheme with the routing ?

Comment: yes. correct.....

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 3.0 , the new Endpoint Routing middleware will enable the feature to get routes values before the router get executed. From the [article](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/) on Dynamic controller routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0 , you could try a new feature called `MapDynamicControllerRoute` and an extensibility point called `DynamicRouteValueTransformer `.